# Ribbon, Change The Text Above The "press F1 For Add-in Help"

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

I would like to change the **text** above the "press F1 for add-in help" in a custom ribbon. Based on my internet research it is not possible to change "press F1 for add-in help". However, I have seen that people change the bold text above it. i.e. **BCERev2.accdb** to **Quote** [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItKjn.png).

How is this text changed? Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Solution MS Access 2010:

The **bold text** above the "press F1 for add-in help" in a custom ribbon is set by the database property "AppTitle".

1. db.Properties("AppTitle").value = "TEST" 'change AppTitle
2. Application.RefreshTitleBar 'refresh the title bar

Use Macro Autokeys to capture {F1} keystroke and open custom help file